# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: raises an Exception

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have tried a number of different ways of having custom cell inside my tableview but none of the works. I have also tried having a subclass of the UITableViewCell but it didn't work either.

So, I rolled back to an easier solution.

I have a prototype Cell inside the TableView - that is is of Class UiTableViewCell with identifier : LocalPostsCell

My code is :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.postsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocalPostsCell" ];

// ... blah blah get values for name/text variables


        UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

        UILabel *descriptionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

        if (name == nil || [name isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            // handle the place not being available
            nameLabel.text= @"";
        } else {
            nameLabel.text = name;
        }

        if (text == nil || [text isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            // handle the place not being available
            descriptionLabel.text = @"";
        } else {
            descriptionLabel.text = text;
        }
return cell;
}
```

I have also tried this :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.postsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocalPostsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

All of them fail at this line and nothing is printed in the console except a (lldb) - Thread 1 - Breakpoint 1.1 error.

I have addd breakpoint for All Exceptions and I have Zombies enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the right Identifier field properly in Interface Builder (it should be `LocalPostsCell`)?

Another possibility is that you are using a different table. As a rule, use the `tableView` variable that comes in the protocol method, not your own reference like `self.postsTable`.

You should also read on in your error message and see what the problem is. You can get more info by pressing the continue button in the debugger.

BTW, you can check implicitly for `nil` so you can be much more concise.

```
nameLabel.text        = name ? name : @"";
descriptionLabel.text = text ? text : @"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you register nib for the CellId? However, you don't alloc anything the first time, do as below:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocalPostsCell" ];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
}
 // Other things...

return cell;
```